# Not able to switch to Sudo or root on my ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.ISO isntalled on VirtualBox

Tags: root

I have used VirtualBox to setup my ubuntu-22.04.2 on Windows 10 Pro machine.
Default user was added as vboxuser and no user is available. Not able to switch to user and update/install any new software.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XliYS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll to the right of that window so you can see the "Unlock" button.
Click it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was UI adjustment issue to unlock the button. Didn't realize that I need to update the screen resolution to get wide screen UI.

And first command tried with ***$sudo su -*** which prompt for the root user pwd, and provided the same VMuser password didn't work.

Tried with "su -" which allowed to turn as ROOT with same VMuser password.